# populating combobox based on the selection of another combobox

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

i have two combo boxes named comboBox1 and comboBox2. the cmbbox1 is filled with item names i have added manually before. upon selecting the item in the cmbbox1, i want to fill the cmbbox2 with the corresponding supplier which drawn from the database. sometime there are more than one supplier for an item. in that case i want to fill the combobox 2 with all the suppliers to allow the user to select the supplier..

```
Dim cn As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim dr As SqlDataReader
Dim dt As New DataTable

     cn.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=NIMO-HP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FYP_db;Integrated Security=True")
     cmd.Connection = cn
     cn.Open()

     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT comName FROM TblSuppliers WHERE comSitem ='" &     ComboBox1.Text & "'"
     dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
     dt.Load(dr)
     ComboBox2.Text =  dt
```

Comment: And what problem do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
Dim cn As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim dt As New DataTable
cn.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=NIMO-HP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FYP_db;Integrated Security=True")
cn.Open()
cmd.Connection = cn
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT comName FROM TblSuppliers WHERE comSitem ='" &     ComboBox1.Text & "'"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
adapter.Fill(dt)
ComboBox2.DataSource = dt
ComboBox2.ValueMember = "comName"
ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "comName"
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Manoj it really worked..
there is another small thing.. when i select the items in the combobox1 for 2 times, the previous data will also stay there.. is there a way to remove the previous data ?

Comment: Well, you can use ComboBox1.DataSource = Nothing before ComboBox2.DataSource = dt.

Comment: i really appreciate your help mr @Manoj . later i figured out the problem.. cz, instead of instantiating the sql data connection in the method, i have instantiate  the sql connection in the begining of the class. so that it will be used commonly by all the methods. this was the reason..